# Java NullPointerException when adding listener to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, actionlistener

I am displaying a table in a Java GUI. The user can currently add rows to the table by clicking an 'Add Row' button, and edit the values of the cells in the table. I am now trying to add a method to remove the selected row from the table by clicking a 'Remove Row' button.

I have declared the button as a global variable:

```
public JButton removeBtn = null;
```

Then I am adding the listener to the button in my `addListeners()` method:

```
private void addListeners(){
    ....
    removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int selectedRow = jEntityFilterTable.getSelectedRow();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();
            model.removeRow(selectedRow);
        }
    });
}
```

However, when I now try to run my code, I get a `NullPointerException` that's stopping it from running... The exception says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

The lines it's complaining about are:

```
removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
```

(which I guess means it could be anything inside the clock of code above, where I'm adding the `ActionListener`),

```
addListeners();
```

(where I'm calling the `addListeners()` method), and

```
JConfigurationPane panel = new JConfigurationPane();
```

(where I'm initialising the `JConfigurationPane` in my `main()` method. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `public JButton removeBtn = null;` It's `null`. You must initialize it *before* adding an `ActionListener` to it

Comment: Where do you initialize your button? From the code you posted `removeBtn` is `null`.

Comment: What @BackSlash said. Plus: "(which I guess means it could be anything inside the block of code above, where I'm adding the ActionListener)" - no. The stuff in that block is your ActionListener. It runs when an action is performed, not when it's added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialised the removeBtn variable. Replace

```
public JButton removeBtn = null;
```

with

```
public JButton removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
```

In your current code, on the line

```
removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
```

removeBtn does not refer to an object so there is nothing to invoke the addActionListener method on. As a result, you receive a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've given that a go, and it has cleared up the `NullPointerException` that I was getting, but for some reason, when I click the button, the selected row is not removed from the table. I've added some debug code to the `actionPerformed()` method, but this is never displayed in the console, so it seems that the code inside the `actionPerformed()` method is never called... Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @someone2088 I would raise a separate SO question for the new issue. Make sure you post the relevant code and what you have tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize your button like this:

```
removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
```